# RPM database not seeing file installed as part of RPM

Tags: rhel, rpm, java, dependencies

**Intro:**

*The following was done on a `RHEL 6.9 32bit` OS.*

I installed the oracle (not openjdk) version of `JRE` rpm using the

`rpm -Uvh`

command.

I then built a package using `rpmbuild` that requires `libjvm.so` which is provided by the oracle JRE and verified this using the command.

`rpm -ql jre1.8.0_111-1.8.0_111-fcs.i586`

**Problem:**

However, when I go to install the `rpm` I built or use the command `rpm -q libjvm.so` I am getting told that `libjvm.so` is not installed.

I know I can put in the `spec` file for my rpm

`AutoReqProv: no`

to get around the dependency issue, however, that does not seem like good practice and I have also rebuilt the rpm database to no avail.

**Question:**

Thus I am left pondering and trying to solve, how the jre rpm says it provides `libjvm.so` yet the RPM database keeps saying that the dependency `libjvm.so` is not installed. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

The JRE rpm also provides the following

```
jaxp_parser_impl  
xml-commons-apis  
java  
java-1.8.0  
java-fonts  
jre  
jre-1.8.0  
jre1.8.0_111 = 1.8.0_111-fcs
```

Comment: What is the oracle RPM providing? `rpm -ql` lists the files; `rpm -q --provides ...` will show whether it "provides" the `libjvm.so`. For packages in `yum` you can also search via `yum whatprovides '*/libjvm.so*'`

Comment: @thrig added an edit for what that gave me.

Comment: That looks like the JRE rpm *does not* provide `libjvm.so`, hence the error.

Comment: @thrig that is strange though since the package does work. is there a way to tell it to only not auto include that dependency and no others in the spec file or is that not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `libjvm.so` requirement in the OpenJDK packages comes from

```
$ rpm -qp --provides java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.121-1.b13.el6.x86_64.rpm \
  2>/dev/null | grep libjvm
libjvm.so()(64bit)
libjvm.so(SUNWprivate_1.1)(64bit)
```

which the Oracle RPM by contrast does not provide. Apart from removing
that requirement from the package you are building (either with the hammer that is `AutoReqProv` or more complicated options involving the [dependency scripts](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html)) another option is to
create a shim package that does nothing more than provide the necessary
requirement (and possibly to `Conflict` with OpenJDK).

```
Name:           shim-libjvm
Version:        1
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        Shim for libjvm

Group:          Development/Languages
License:        CC BY-SA 3.0
URL:            http://example.org

Provides:       libjvm.so

BuildArchitectures: noarch

%description
Shim for libjvm

%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/usr/share/doc/shim-libjvm
echo "shim-libjvm is merely a provider for libjvm.so" > %{buildroot}/usr/share/doc/shim-libjvm/README


%files
%doc
/usr/share/doc/shim-libjvm/README

%changelog
* Thu Jun  8 2017 John Doe <jdoe@example.org>
- Release on a mostly unsuspecting world.
```