# Can yum detect dependencies installed via pip?

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, pip

Environment is CentOS 7.3.1611.

I deploy an application that depends on a few packages that seem to have disappeared from the EPEL. These packages are:

- python-turbocheetah
- python-cherrypy2
- python-turbojson
- python-paste-script
- python-peak-rules
- python-turbokid

Not sure why they've disappeared from the repositories, so that's another question. Luckily, I am still able to install these packages using pip. However, yum doesn't seem to be able to detect that they've been installed, so installing the application's RPM still fails on missing dependencies.

Is there any way to get yum to detect that these packages are actually installed?

Thanks!

Comment: You can if necessary fake RPM database entries with "shim" packages e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370001/rpm-database-not-seeing-file-installed-as-part-of-rpm/370068#370068

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yum` can only detect things which are installed with `rpm` or tools that use it (such as `yum` itself).  As `pip` does not use `rpm`, there is no way for `yum` to know about anything that `pip` manages.

Comment: Ah, I was worried this was the case, but didn't know anything about the underlying mechanisms. Thank you.