# installed cabextract manually using make install, but its not available when using rpm

Tags: centos, rpm, make

```
[root@mybox ~]# cabextract --v
cabextract version 1.9.1
[root@mybox ~]# rpm -i https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mscorefonts2/rpms/msttcore-fonts-installer-2.6-1.noarch.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        cabextract is needed by msttcore-fonts-installer-2.6-1.noarch
[root@mybox ~]#
```

End goal of trying to install windows fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `make install` will not modify the RPM database. You must install an RPM, ideally the cabextract package that "provides" the necessary requirement. (The requirement could also be [faked via a custom package build](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370001/rpm-database-not-seeing-file-installed-as-part-of-rpm/370068#370068), which is not ideal but can work sometimes.) Setting up `yum` or similar may help chase RPM dependencies automatically, instead of downloading and installing individual packages manually.

Answer (score 1):

```
yum install glibc.i686
rpm -i cabextract-1.9.1-1.i386.rpm (dl'd from https://cabextract.org.uk/)
rpm -i https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mscorefonts2/rpms/msttcore-fonts-installer-2.6-1.noarch.rpm
```